# Using an NSString as a Name of a Label For Loops

Tags: objective-c, theory

I have a lot of labels and it would be handy if I could use a string in the place of the label's name to access their properties(like .center). This would greatly reduce the number of lines typed. I need to change the same property of all labels multiple times. If I were to have a loop that said something like:

```
NSString *TheLabelName = @"MyLabel#  "
for(int TheNumber = 1; TheNumber < Something; TheNumber++){

   TheNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i",TheNumber] ;
   TheLabelName = [TheLabelName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString: TheNumberString] ;
   TheLabelName.center = CGPointMake...
}
```

I couldn't find anything like this on Google or Stack. Is there any possible way to use a string in the place of a name of a label?

Comment: Put the labels into an array, then access by index

Comment: That is not a good pattern. Perhaps create an array of the labels and iterate that list with a `for label in labelList)`.

Comment: The reason why you couldn't find anything is because there isn't anything.  But put away the Objective-C for awhile and go get a C or Java book and learn about "arrays".  They do the same thing, only much simpler.

Comment: (If you're even asking this question you're over your head in Objective-C and need to go back to C or Java to learn some fundamentals first.)

Comment: Thank you danielbeard and Zaph . Hot Licks Thank you, but no I am "not in over my head" I have a good understanding of Objective-C. I  was just seeing if there was any way to do something like this. Thank you for your "help".

Comment: Maybe look into KVC. See this [apple reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll check it out. It looks like the answer for my question(but maybe not, I've only read the first line :D)